# Read text file and look for certain words from key word list

Tags: python, list, search, count, words

I am new to Python, and I am trying to build a script where I import text_file_1 that contains a body of text. I want the script to read the body of text, and look for certain words that I have defined in a list called (key_words) that contain words with a Capital letter in the beginning (Nation) and lowercase (nation). After Python does the searching, it will output the list of words vertically in a new text file called "List of Words", along with the number of times that word occurs in the body. If I read text_file_2 with a body of text, it will do the same, but ADD to the List of Words from the original file.

Example:

List of Words

File 1:

```
God: 5
Nation: 4
creater: 8
USA: 3
```

File 2:

```
God: 10
Nation: 14
creater: 2
USA: 1
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
from sys import argv
from string import punctuation

script = argv[0] all_filenames = argv[1:]

print "Text file to import and read: " + all_filenames
print "\nReading file...\n"
text_file = open(all_filenames, 'r')
all_lines = text_file.readlines()
#print all_lines
text_file.close()

for all_filenames in argv[1:]:
   print "I get: " + all_filenames

print "\nFile read finished!"
#print "\nYour file contains the following text information:"
#print "\n" + text_file.read()

#~ for word, count in word_freq.items():
    #~ print word, count

keyWords = ['God', 'Nation', 'nation', 'USA', 'Creater', 'creater', 'Country', 'Almighty',
             'country', 'People', 'people', 'Liberty', 'liberty', 'America', 'Independence', 
             'honor', 'brave', 'Freedom', 'freedom', 'Courage', 'courage', 'Proclamation',
             'proclamation', 'United States', 'Emancipation', 'emancipation', 'Constitution',
             'constitution', 'Government', 'Citizens', 'citizens']

for word in keyWords:
    if word in word_freq:
        output_file.write( "%s: %d\n" % (word, word_freq[word]) )

output_file = open("List_of_words.txt", "w")

for word in keyWords:
    if word in word_freq:
        output_file.write( "%s: %d\n" % (word, word_freq[word]) )

output_file.close()
```

Maybe use this code somehow?

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input('List_of_words.txt', inplace = True):
    if line.startswith('Existing file that was read'):
        #if line starts Existing file that was read then do something here
        print "Existing file that was read"
    elif line.startswith('New file that was read'):
        #if line starts with New file that was read then do something here
        print "New file that was read"
    else:
        print line.strip()
```

Comment: Show your code. What is your problem ?

Comment: getting used to posting code

Comment: You have forgotten to tell us what the problem that you need help with is.

Comment: my problem is I'm not sure how to go about doing the comparison and then inputting it into a new file. I've been reading my books about it but its a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

This way you have result on the screen.

```
from sys import argv
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation

script, filename = argv

text_file = open(filename, 'r')

word_freq = Counter([word.strip(punctuation) for line in text_file for word in line.split()])

#~ for word, count in word_freq.items():
    #~ print word, count

key_words = ['God', 'Nation', 'nation', 'USA', 'Creater', 'creater'
             'Country', 'country', 'People', 'people', 'Liberty', 'liberty',
             'honor', 'brave', 'Freedom', 'freedom', 'Courage', 'courage']

for word in key_words:
    if word in word_freq:
        print word, word_freq[word]
```

Now you have to save it in file.

For more files use

```
for filename in argv[1:]:
   # do your job
```

---

**EDIT:**

With this code  (my_script.py)

```
for filename in argv[1:]:
   print( "I get", filename )
```

You can run script

```
python my_script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

and get

```
I get file1.txt 
I get file2.txt 
I get file3.txt
```

You can use it to count words in many files.

-

Using `readlines()` you read all lines into memory so you need more memory - for very, very big file it can be problem.

In current version `Counter()` count all words in all lines - test it - but use less memory.
So using `readlines()` you get the same `word_freq` but you use more memory.

-

`writelines(list_of_result)` will not add "\n" after every line - and don't add ':' in "God: 3"

Better use something similar to

```
output_file = open("List_of_words.txt", "w")

for word in key_words:
    if word in word_freq:
        output_file.write( "%s: %d\n" % (word, word_freq[word]) )

output_file.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** new version - it append result to the end of List_of_words.txt

```
from sys import argv
from string import punctuation
from collections import *

keyWords = ['God', 'Nation', 'nation', 'USA', 'Creater', 'creater', 'Country', 'Almighty',
             'country', 'People', 'people', 'Liberty', 'liberty', 'America', 'Independence', 
             'honor', 'brave', 'Freedom', 'freedom', 'Courage', 'courage', 'Proclamation',
             'proclamation', 'United States', 'Emancipation', 'emancipation', 'Constitution',
             'constitution', 'Government', 'Citizens', 'citizens']


for one_filename in argv[1:]:

    print "Text file to import and read:", one_filename
    print "\nReading file...\n"

    text_file = open(one_filename, 'r')
    all_lines = text_file.readlines()
    text_file.close()

    print "\nFile read finished!"

    word_freq = Counter([word.strip(punctuation) for line in all_lines for word in line.split()])

    print "Append result to the end of file: List_of_words.txt"

    output_file = open("List_of_words.txt", "a")

    for word in keyWords:
        if word in word_freq:
            output_file.write( "%s: %d\n" % (word, word_freq[word]) )

    output_file.close()
```

---

**EDIT:** write sum of results in one file

```
from sys import argv
from string import punctuation
from collections import *

keyWords = ['God', 'Nation', 'nation', 'USA', 'Creater', 'creater', 'Country', 'Almighty',
             'country', 'People', 'people', 'Liberty', 'liberty', 'America', 'Independence', 
             'honor', 'brave', 'Freedom', 'freedom', 'Courage', 'courage', 'Proclamation',
             'proclamation', 'United States', 'Emancipation', 'emancipation', 'Constitution',
             'constitution', 'Government', 'Citizens', 'citizens']

word_freq = Counter()

for one_filename in argv[1:]:

    print "Text file to import and read:", one_filename
    print "\nReading file...\n"

    text_file = open(one_filename, 'r')
    all_lines = text_file.readlines()
    text_file.close()

    print "\nFile read finished!"

    word_freq.update( [word.strip(punctuation) for line in all_lines for word in line.split()] )

print "Write sum of results: List_of_words.txt"

output_file = open("List_of_words.txt", "w")

for word in keyWords:
    if word in word_freq:
        output_file.write( "%s: %d\n" % (word, word_freq[word]) )

output_file.close()
```

Comment: Yes I see it, I tried it and so far it does it right. What I noticed is that it continues to add to the Word List, and not update it. So I have to figure out how I can make it update and not continue to add everytime I read the same text file, and also format it in a way where it will display the file that was read and under it will display the word count

Comment: set `w` (w=write) in place of `a` (a=append) in `open()` - if you means update without `summing results`

Comment: If you need `sum of results` you need change `Counter()`. See new code in my answer (above).

Comment: I will have to use a(a=append) because the "w" will overwrite what is already in the file. I would want it to basically read one file, add it, then if it reads another file, add it also, but not overwrite, just simply update it below the first one. If I choose to read 3 text files, then it will add all 3 at once, one below the other. If it sees that the same file was read, then it wont do anything if it already exists